# Spring MVC Returning a Blank View To User

Tags: java, html, spring-mvc

I have a form when the user inserts a record into the database they may wish to create a new record at the same time and they can click on a new button. I have a Controller defined to accept this command and return to the user a blank view only with the list boxes being populated, however the view is not coming back blank it has the data from the previous insert into the database.

**Code:**

User select the following button

```
<button class="btn" value="new" onclick="submitPage('${pageContext.request.contextPath}/crime_registration_new.htm');" type="button" >New</button>
```

**Controller Method:**

I would like to get rid of the old crime object

```
    @RequestMapping(value="crime_registration_new.htm", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView loadNew(HttpServletRequest request, 
        HttpServletResponse response,
        @ModelAttribute Crime crime,
        Model model) throws Exception {

    try{

        logger.debug("In Crime Registration Controller");

        myCriminalList.put("dbcriminalList", this.citizenManager.getListOfCriminals());
        myVictimList.put("dbvictimList", this.citizenManager.getListOfVictims());
        myStatusList.put("statusList", this.statusManager.getStatusList());
        myCrimeCategoryList.put("crimeCategoryList", this.crimeCategoryManager.getCrimeCategoryList());
        myCrimeLevelList.put("crimeLevelList", this.crimeLevelManager.getCrimeLevelList());
        myOfficerList.put("investigatingOfficerList", this.officerManager.getOfficersList());

        model.addAttribute("dbcriminals", myCriminalList);
        model.addAttribute("dbvictims",   myVictimList);
        model.addAttribute("status", myStatusList);
        model.addAttribute("crimeCategory", myCrimeCategoryList);
        model.addAttribute("crimeLevel",myCrimeLevelList);
        model.addAttribute("officers",myOfficerList);
        model.addAttribute("crimeRecordNoStatus", "true");
        model.addAttribute("crimeRecordNoStatus", "true");
        model.addAttribute("save", "enabled");

        return  new ModelAndView("crime_registration");          
    }catch(Exception e){                
        logger.debug("Exception In CrimeRegistration Controller : " + e.getMessage());
        return new ModelAndView("crime_registration");               
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`myCriminalList`, `myVictimList`, etc. don't seem to be `local variables` but `instance variables` so they're shared and accessible by subsequent method calls. Make sure you declare these fields as local so they're bound to that single request and can't be seen outside that request scope.

```
@RequestMapping(value="crime_registration_new.htm", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView loadNew( (...) ) throws Exception {
        // local variable - only accessible by current request
        List<Criminal> myCriminalList = new ArrayList<Criminal>();

        myCriminalList.put("dbcriminalList",
                this.citizenManager.getListOfCriminals());
        model.addAttribute("dbcriminals", myCriminalList);
        return new ModelAndView("crime_registration");
        // (...)
}
```

---

And as a side-note, why not simplify it even further:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "crime_registration_new.htm", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView loadNew( (...) ) throws Exception {
        // no need for intermediary List
        model.addAttribute("dbcriminals", this.citizenManager.getListOfCriminals());
        // (...)
        return new ModelAndView("crime_registration");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I set the Controller method to return String and i used the following to send the user back to the view:

```
return "redirect: crime_registration.htm";
```